# Alternate Reference Implementation C++

Tags: c++, compilation, reference

As far as I can tell, in c++ references are implemented as constant pointers.

say you have y, which is a reference to variable x.
why would it not be more performant and efficient (especially when passing variables in functions). To either:
A. every time y is mentioned it gets replaced by x as a pre-processing stage.
B. have both x and y refer to the same memory address in the compilers symbol table.

Comment: Optimisers do exactly this

Comment: @AlanBirtles cool, I didn't know that. I assume this is an optional optimization though, in which case why would it not be the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I can tell, in c++ references are implemented as constant pointers.

Might be correct, might be not. I actually don't know for sure. In any case thats implementation details. What matters is how the C++ standard specifies reference and it does not mention that they must be implemented as constant pointers.

> why would it not be more performant and efficient...

When it is possible and more performant the compiler will do that. The so-called [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) allows the compiler to perform any optimization that does not change observable behavior of the program in accordance with the C++ standard. The standard does not specify how references are implemented in detail. It is up to the compiler to implement them in the most efficient way.